# ModuleNotFoundError: no module named Python Error

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import line
from python import display
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [12], line 3
      1 import numpy as np
      2 from numpy.random import default_rng
----> 3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      4 import line
      5 from python import display

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng

from python import display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import line
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [13], line 4
      1 import numpy as np
      2 from numpy.random import default_rng
----> 4 from python import display
      5 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      6 import line

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python'
```

i wonna make graph...................................................................................

Comment: Why are you trying to `from python import display` in the first place?

Comment: Have you installed `matplotlib`?

Answer (score 0):

`ModuleNotFoundError` means there is a problem trying import a module into your application. Often this is because you don't have the module available locally (i.e. not installed). It can also be because you've mistyped the import statement or are trying to import the module using the wrong name.

In your case:

`from python import display` doesn't make much sense.
Python is not a package, as far as I'm aware. Where did this line of code come from? Where is the `display()` function you are trying to use?

```
----> 3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

This means the matplotlib library is not installed.
You can install it using:

`python3 -m pip install matplotlib`